# Reactive Mono::zip with interdependency between elements

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have, as a simple example, a mono that depends on another mono. Normally I would use `Mono::flatMap` to chain the publishers. However I found out that using `Mono::zip` also works. Is this "allowed" or a good or bad idea? Why?

```
Mono<String> a = Mono.just("A");
Mono<String> b = Mono.just("B");
Mono<String> c = Mono.just("C");
Mono<String> d = Mono.just("D");
Mono<String> ae = a.flatMap(am->Mono.just(am.concat("E")));
Mono.zip(a, b, c, d, ae).subscribe(System.out::println);
```

As an additional thought:

```
Mono<String> monoA = Mono.just("A");
Mono<String> monoB = Mono.just("B");
Mono<String> a = something(monoA);
Mono<String> b = something(monoB);
Mono<String> c = something(monoA);
Mono<String> d = something(monoA);
Mono<String> ae = something(a);
Mono.zip(a, b, c, d, ae).subscribe(System.out::println);
```

Updates: I can add a routine to simulate the use case of calling an API like so:

```
private Mono<String> getOne() {
    System.out.println("Here 1");
    return Mono.just("A");
}
```

Then I can change the first line, as suggested below to

```
Mono<String> a = Mono.from(getOne()).doOnNext(System.out::println);
```

This indeed shows `a` being emitted twice but only constructed once. Being emitted twice might be a small price to pay when considering the "correct" way to handle this situation, like so:

```
Mono<String> a = Mono.from(getOne()).doOnNext(System.out::println);
Mono<String> b = Mono.just("B");
Mono<String> c = Mono.just("C");
Mono<String> d = Mono.just("D");
Mono.zip(a, b, c, d).flatMap(tuple4->{
    return Mono.just(tuple4.getT1().concat("E")).map(ae->{
        // here I have everything I need   
        return String.format("[%s,%s,%s,%s,%s]", tuple4.getT1(), tuple4.getT2(), tuple4.getT3(), tuple4.getT4(), ae);
    });
}).subscribe(System.out::println);
```

Comment: In your example Mono 'a' gets subscribed and executed twice, which is probably not desired. However, you can use the cache operator to prevent that.

Comment: It doesn't print twice.

Comment: put a doOnNext with a print on your mono 'a', that will print twice

Comment: Yes, good point. However, that just means the same Mono is emitted twice but it only gets "created" once. If I'm willing to live with that do you think there are other issues?

Comment: The construction of the Mono is usually not the interesting part. It's the source of the Mono which is interesting. For example if this is an HTTP call, then that HTTP call will be made twice. This is the problem with dummy examples, it's difficult to give proper advice, unless we see what is the actual real world problem here.

Comment: Well, okay, perhaps construction is not the right word. When I used WebClient only one HTTP call was made and the results emitted twice, same as this example. I assume part of the 'construction' process for WebClient is to make the HTTP call and then emit the results when needed. Still wonder about whether using `zip` in this way is supposed to be allowed or a good idea or not.

Comment: I can guarantee you that the HTTP call is made twice in that case... HTTP call from WebClient is triggered on subscription, not on construction and your code subscribes twice to it. Ultimately, that's why your approach is not recommended, unless you maybe use cache operator as I mentioned before.

Comment: Okay, works for me. I thought I had checked it I probably overlooked something. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

in a flatmap `publisher` A needs to finish until you can execute B, so it will be executed in serial.

when using zip, `publisher` A or B can finish first or second, it doesn't matter, it will not continue until both are finished. It will be run in parallell.

you can also look into the `zipWith` function, which is a way of combining `publishers` in a serial fashion.